# use case for constructors for gsl::not_null taking value type

Tags: c++11

gsl::not_null has 2 constructors one taking a forwarding reference and another one taking a value type. What is the case where the forwarding constructor alone would not work? Implementation from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/main/include/gsl/pointers)

```cpp
template <class T>
class not_null
{
public:
    static_assert(details::is_comparable_to_nullptr<T>::value, "T cannot be compared to nullptr.");

    template <typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U, T>::value>>
    constexpr not_null(U&& u) : ptr_(std::forward<U>(u))
    {
        Expects(ptr_ != nullptr);
    }

    template <typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::nullptr_t, T>::value>>
    constexpr not_null(T u) : ptr_(std::move(u))
    {
        Expects(ptr_ != nullptr);
    }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commit history gives the answer - https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/commit/cb2d1af89afb76bf50efe8e068c5ea1fc2872274

> This allows compilers with c++17 support to infer template
> instantiation types when calling not_null constructor:

```
int foo(not_null<const int*> x);

int main()
{
    int t = 0;
    not_null x{ &t };
    return foo(not_null{ &t });
}
```

i.e. with this constructor you can write just `not_null x{ &t }` instead of `not_null<int *> x{ &t }`.

Comment: ```foo()``` works due to [converting constructor](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/6c6111acb7b5d687ac006969ac96e5b1f21374cd/include/gsl/pointers#L113)